# Compile a list of projects with msbuild.exe

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS solution which contains n-`C++ projects`. Is there any way to let `msbuild.exe` compile a specific subset of projects via command line?

```
msbuild.exe foo.sln /thisFlagWouldBeCool:project1;project2
```

I tried the `/t` flag for targets, but that doesn't seem to do it, since targets are not projects?

Comment: See [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019) , hope I don't misunderstand that:)

Comment: Hi Daniel, any update for this issue? If it still blocks you, feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

1.See [How to: Build specific targets in solutions by using MSBuild.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-build-specific-targets-in-solutions-by-using-msbuild-exe?view=vs-2019). As it states, you can use command like:

```
msbuild SlnFolders.sln -target:NotInSlnfolder:Rebuild;NewFolder\InSolutionFolder:Clean
```

More specific, if you have `Project A, B, C` in same solution(Test.sln), to build only A and B, you can use command like:

```
msbuild Test.sln /t:A;B /p:Configuration="xx" /p:Platform="xx"
```

**Note**: To build in this way, we should make sure the `A.xxproj` and `B.xxproj` are defined in `xx.sln` file. At least for VS, if we create a new Project C, the `xx.sln` won't be updated until we click the `save all` button.

2.And here's another direction which is suitable for some **specific** scenario:

We can right-click the Solution node in VS, choose `add project=>empty project` to add an empty project into the solution, let's name it `MyBuildTool` project.Unload it to edit its `MyBuildTool.vcxproj` file, add this kind of script into the bottom of it(within the Project tab):

```
  <!--If you're trying to build subset  of the solution, any build the projects with different settings-->
  <Target Name="CustomBuild" AfterTargets="build">
    <MSBuild Projects="..\**\B2.vcxproj" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=x64;OutDir=xxx"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="..\**\A2.vcxproj" Properties="Configuration=Release"/>
    ...
  </Target>

  <!--If you're building several projects in same settings-->
  <Target Name="CustomBuild" AfterTargets="build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\**\A1.vcxproj"/>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\**\B1.vcxproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" BuildInParallel="true"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then the MyBuildTool.vcxproj is now our build script, if in some specific situation we need to build several project, we can just run command `msbuild.exe MyBuildTool.vcxproj`. It depends on the usage of [MSBuild Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I exactly tried that but it says the targets don't exist (but that's the name of the project)

Comment: Is the command you use the same as what mentioned above in your question? I will check it then later :)

Comment: Yes, pretty much, and it says the targets do not exist. Very odd `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" mysolution.sln /t:project1 /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64"`

Comment: Before you execute the command, open the `mysolution.sln` with notepad to see if the `project1` which throws the error message is defined in the `xx.sln` file. I guess your xx.sln might not be updated after you create the project...(Save all can help?)

Comment: Hm, I can see the project in the `Project(` section of the `sln`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in my machine..Is the project1 under your solution directory, I mean sometimes we add an existing project into solution, same scenario? And I suggest you can use [Developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to run the command. Open the DCP and cd to the folder where the xx.sln exists, and type command `msbuild xx.sln /t:xxx...`. If it still can't work, maybe you can share the content of xx.sln file, and the failed build log you get(Error MSB4057?) in question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200685/discussion-between-lance-li-msft-and-daniel-stephens).